# return PDF Doc via post via jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf

I am working in Spring 3, Java, JSP, javascript, and jquery, using Ajax occasionally. I have server functions that generate a PDF; I have a new requirement to show a "preview" of a PDF document.

I have code that generates the PDF document, that works fine. I can show it by hacking my source to display it in the place we normally show the un-watermarked completed document, so I know the generation of the PDF is working.

What I now want to do is display that PDF in its own tab as the result of clicking on a button (or link) on our web page. There are a few restrictions:

1. I have a bunch of data to pass up to the controller from the web page, data that it needs to generate the PDF. We have code that does this through a POST method, and use Ajax to post the necessary data.
2. It would be inconvenient for the PDF to show up in the same window as the button clicked to show the PDF; a popup asking if the user wants to download or view elsewhere is fine. The users aren't sophisticated enough to depend on theiri knowledge of the 'back' button here. So we want the PDF to show up elsewhere, preferably on another tab in the window but another entire window would be ok.

I have the following in my controller at the moment:

```
        response.setContentLength(pdfGenerated.length);
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Preview.pdf\"");

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        out.write(pdfGenerated); // (encodedPdf);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

The ajax call looks like this:

```
$("#generatePDFPreview").live("click", function() {
    var gridData = getCorrectedGridData();
    var valid = validateContractContent(gridData);
    if (valid) {
        // the call below saves the contract data and then generates its PDF
        $.ajax({
            url: getModelObject("generatePDFPreviewURL")
            ,type:'POST'
            ,data: {'editedContents':JSON.stringify(gridData)}
            ,datatype: "application/pdf"
            ,async: false
            ,success: function(data) {                
                if(data != null && data.length>0 && data != "Error") {    
                    //data must be contract id...use it to build the complete URL.
                    //window.location.href = getModelObject("deliveryScreenURL") + data;
                    window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data);
                } else {
                    alert("PDF preview not generated...Data returned is not ok. Please try again or contact Sales Support.");
                }                
            }
        });   
    }
});
```

I have tried different things here; I have left off the 'success' function entirely; I have tried encoding the data (base64) and returning that, and using data:application/pdf, etc., but that failed -- I have some evidence that the PDF data was too long for this, but am not sure (it was 85k-90k, the URL string stopped at something like 32784).

I am not worried about whether my user has the PDF reader installed. They must have it installed to use this and other parts of the application.

It is frustrating to be so close; all evidence is that we have most of the pieces in place, it's should just be a matter of telling the browser that we want it to use the PDF Reader to handle these bytes.

Can someone point us to a method, or point out what's wrong with what we've got now?

Comment: take a look at the JS behind www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf it has all the various options. in your case you will need to use embed/object tag in the new window and not the URL with base64 data I believe

Comment: Thanks, I will look at cloudformatter - I actually solved this problem by using an onClick JS routine to write the data to the database, then an href target in the link to have the controller retrieve the data and return the PDF. It would be nice(r) if I could do this without two server trips, but this serves my needs for now. I will write it up as an answer after I get past my current deadline.